# Language fallback for Non-Shared fields are not working with Glass mapper and Sitecore 9?

Tags: glass-mapper, language-fallback

I have a site configured with an item and field language fallback. We are using glassmapper as an ORM. We have used **VersionCountDisabler** in the code and global.asax level.

Settings:

- enableItemLanguageFallback="true"
- enableFieldLanguageFallback="true"
- enforceVersionPresence="true"

In the Content editor, it shows fallback version with all the values from the fallback item.

However, it is returning an empty value for the **non-shared** fields. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I fixed it by following the below steps:

1. Enable language settings at **site level** in config file under  configuration as below:

   ```
   <site
   name="custom-portal"
   hostName="portal"
   virtualFolder="/"
   physicalFolder="/"
   rootPath="/sitecore/content/portal"
   startItem="/home"
   database="web"
   domain="extranet"
   allowDebug="true"
   cacheHtml="true"
   htmlCacheSize="10MB"
   registryCacheSize="0"
   viewStateCacheSize="0"
   xslCacheSize="5MB"
   filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB"
   enablePreview="true"
   enableWebEdit="true"
   enableDebugger="true"
   disableClientData="false"
   notFoundItem="/Error-404"
   patch:before="site[@name='website']"
   dictionaryDomain="PortalDictionary"

   enableItemLanguageFallback="true"
   enableFieldLanguageFallback="true"
   enforceVersionPresence="true"
   />
   ```
2. Enable language fall-back setting at **language level** under Sitecore->System->Languages in Sitecore
   [image]
3. Enable language fall-back setting at **template level**. **Then only glassmapper will read the non-shared fields**.

[image]

4. Add **VersionCountDisabler** in global.ascx.cs, which is required by the glassmapper and this is the most important step.

[image]